# Totaling up a column on a Gridview and display in the footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am new to asp.net and I am having trouble trying to add up the itemstotal values in my shoppingcart. The code I have doesn't work but I feel like I am on the right track. Can someone help me?

ShoppingCart.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblItemTotal" runat="server" DataFormatString="{0:c2}"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="Order Total: "></asp:Label>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

ShoppingCart.aspx.cs

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProductsList.Rows)
{
   Label lblItemTotal = (Label)row.FindControl("lblItemTotal");//find itemTotal label
   decimal decPrice = decimal.Parse(lblItemTotal.Text, NumberStyles.Currency);//convert to decimal
   decimal newtotal =+ decPrice;
   Label lblTotal = (row.FindControl("lblTotal")) as Label;
   lblTotal.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(newtotal);
 }
```

I get a nullexception for the line 
lblTotal.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(newtotal);

Comment: what event is your `foreach` loop in?

Comment: it is in a buttonclick event to update the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a newbie myself, but I think inside your foreach loop you need to either check if the row you're looking at is indeed a footer before pointing to the label inside of the footer, or, I believe, you can get your footer row with:

```
var footerRow = gvProductsList.FooterRow;
```

EDIT:
I don't have VS with me right now, but try this:

```
decimal newtotal;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProductsList.Rows)
{
   Label lblItemTotal = (Label)row.FindControl("lblItemTotal");
   decimal decPrice = decimal.Parse(lblItemTotal.Text, NumberStyles.Currency); 
   newtotal =+ decPrice;
 }
 var footerRow = gvProductsList.FooterRow;
 Label lblTotal = (footerRow.FindControl("lblTotal")) as Label;
 lblTotal.Text = "$" + Convert.ToString(newtotal);
```

Comment: Do I just add that line before pointing to the label? I'm sill getting a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I've tried that and got some value to display in the total however the number displayed is only the product total of the last product on the list, not the added up total.

Comment: @Jamie Oh! Switch equal sign and plus sign. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you so much!!